# Blazor - Dynamically create an input text list and bind the values that user inputs to same

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I am having a list that contains countries list. I want to create a page where it will display the list as input boxes with label as country name.

user can input the city inside the country and the value of city should be bind with Country name.

Sample -

private List CountryNames = new List<String).

```
@foreach (string qitem in CountryNames )
{
    <input type="text" @bind="@qitem" />
}
```

Getting error that Qitem cannot be assigned as it's a foreach loop iterator.

What is needed

1. Input boxes should be created based on list items
2. bind the value with the countryname. So, if i print the variable countryname it will give me user input.

Tried various options but dynamically input boxes are not getting created with bind value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some demo code that shows you two ways to do it:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

@foreach(var country in this.countries)
{
    <div class="mb-2">
        <span class="form-label">@country.Name</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@country.CapitalCity" @oninput="(e) => UpdateCity(country, e)" />
    </div>
}

@foreach (var country in this.countries)
{
    <div class="mb-2">
        <span class="form-label">@country.Name</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind:event="oninput" @bind=@country.CapitalCity />
    </div>
}

@foreach (var country in this.countries)
{
    <div class="mb-2">
        @country.Name - @country.CapitalCity
    </div>
}

@code {
    private List<Country> countries = new List<Country>
    {
        new Country {Name = "UK"},
        new Country {Name = "France"},
        new Country {Name = "Spain"}
    };

    private void UpdateCity(Country country, ChangeEventArgs e)
        => country.CapitalCity = e.Value?.ToString() ?? null;

    public class Country
    {
        public required string Name { get; set; }
        public string? CapitalCity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]